# In The Matrix Resurrections, can Neo see the real image of Trinity or only her Digital Self Image (DSI)?

Tags: the-matrix

Can Neo see Trinity like she actually looks like or just her DSI? And what about how Trinity sees Neo?

Answer (score 1):

Neo seems startled when he sees a reflection in the table that shows her as a blond woman. It seems likely that he sees her *as she should be*, rather than the altered DSI that the new Matrix is attempting to present to everyone else.

[image]

It's not clear how Trinity sees Neo, but we can probably assume that much the same holds true for her as for him since she has a very similar set of superpowers. Note also that she isn't startled by his appearance when she sees him later on (jacked in) and not subject to the same controls over his DSI as before.